# case statement only reaching the default case

Tags: command-line

```
echo "Choose one or All"
        read -n1 $sel
        echo "value of $sel
        case $selection in 
        o|O) echo "inside O";;
        a|A) echo "inside A";;
        *) echo "this is default"
        ;;
        esac;
```

However, it always print value of $sel is default. The case statement is always reaching the default value and it is not reaching other cases. What might be the issue?

Comment: You need to be consistent about whether the variable is `$sel` or `$selection` and also it should be `read -n1 sel` (no `$`). You also have an unmatched `"` which I assume is a copy error.

Comment: You might want to check out `select` statement. e.g. `select sel in one all; do break; done; echo $sel;`

Comment: @steeldriver fixed all these things now, still no luck.

Comment: @plumo this returns empty string

Comment: @Aviator you may [edit] your question to correct the code. It's really impossible to debug code we can't see.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @Aviator , you give the number, not the text. So enter "1" or "2" , then enter. And `$sel` will be the `one` or `all`.